# Nested if else not working

Tags: android, if-statement

My nested if else is not working.

Here is the code:

```
if(s.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Margherita")){
    if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Personal")){
        rowbill=65*n;
    }
            if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Medium")){
        rowbill=125*n;
    }
            if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Family")){
        rowbill=240*n;
    }

}else if(s.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Simply Veg")){
    if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Personal")){
        rowbill=75*n;
    }
    if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Medium")){
        rowbill=145*n;
    }
    if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Family")){
        rowbill=285*n;
    }
}else if(s.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Veggie Crunch")){
    if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Personal")){
        rowbill=100*n;
    }
    if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Medium")){
        rowbill=195*n;
    }
    if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Family")){
        rowbill=350*n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a `if else` or `if else if` statements

Comment: Could you write a little test case demonstrating why this doesn't work?

Comment: @Shashank: "if else if" I think

Comment: @Jeff: See when I select Margheriata from the spinner, the rowbill gives me the right value depending upon the pizzasize...but in case of any other pizza, rowbill gives 0. so this means only the first 'if' is working....:-(

Comment: That entire construct would be easier and much cleaner to implement using `enum`s and a switch/case statements.

Comment: what does s.getSelectedItem() contain and from where does it come from? Are you sure it does conytain, for instance, "Veggie Crunch" (with the spaces). You may want to try printing them.

Comment: I'd suggest sticking a break point on the first line of the if statements, debugging the code and following the flow when you select something other than magherita, inspecting  the values as you go to make sure they're what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanx friend. I fixed it. It was a spelling mistake....I cant believe I did it.. :D Thanx for your help :-)

Answer (score 2):

As you probably have not discovered a failure with the compiler, the trouble is due to your structure.

Simplify it by removing the else's. Yes, you'll end doing up to two String equals() more each time. You can affor it.

Write it as

```
System.out.println("Marguerite");
if (s.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Marguerite")) {
    System.out.println("Marguerite");
    ....
}
if (s.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Simply Veg")) {
    System.out.println("Simply Veg");
    ....
}
```

The error will be then easier to spot. Once solved, you can go back to nested if-else-if if you want to.

Comment: If you're going to goto the effort of printing stuff... perhaps you should try printing out s.getSelectedItem().toString() before your if blocks to make sure your spinner is returning the expected value

Comment: ya I have done that...Spinners return the right value...The only problem is with the of else.

Comment: Now you know the error is somewhere else, and not due the nested if-elses... Are you sure you are getting "Simply Veg" or "Veggie Crunch" right? I find odd that it does not work with the ones with a whitespace, maybe it is an issue with spaces or capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

i think missing or extra '{','}' somewhere.

a logic bug maybe, 'cause compiler doesn't show error or warning.

Comment: ya even I think thats the problem. But I feel the syntax is all right...The brackets have been indented properly.

Comment: @mohit: if you swap your second if block with your first one (check for 'Simply Veg' first instead of 'Marguerita' does 'Marguerita' still work?

Comment: @mohit: If putting 'Simply Veg' at the top doesn't work, and Margherita continues to work, then either, the contents of s.selectedItem, or s1.selectedItem aren't what you're expecting.

Comment: o God...Please dont laugh guys but I was making the dumbest of mistakes...The spelling mistake...Simply was spelled 'Simpy' in the spinner...Thats why the if wasnt working....Now everything works fine...Sorry for troubling you all..:D\

Comment: oh, you got it finally, huh :)

Answer (score 0):

It may work...

```
`if(s.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Margherita")){
if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Personal")){
    rowbill=65*n;
}
else if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Medium")){
    rowbill=125*n;
}
else if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Family")){
    rowbill=240*n;
}

}else if(s.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Simply Veg")){
if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Personal")){
    rowbill=75*n;
}
else if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Medium")){
    rowbill=145*n;
}
else if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Family")){
    rowbill=285*n;
}
}else if(s.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Veggie Crunch")){
if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Personal")){
    rowbill=100*n;
}
else if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Medium")){
    rowbill=195*n;
}
else if(s1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Family")){
    rowbill=350*n;
}
}`
```